# Recursive delete in c#

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a parent that I want to delete. It looks like this :

```
-Parent
 - Child 1
   -Subchild 1
   -Subchild 2
```

When I delete parent, I want to also delete Subchild. This is my code :

```
public void DeleteMenu(int id)
    {
        var item = this.db.Menus.Single(x => x.Id == id);

        //DELETE FOREIGN KEYS
        //MenuLanguageSet
        var languages = from listLanguages in this.db.MenuLanguageSet
                        where listLanguages.idMenu == id
                        select listLanguages;

        foreach (var itemLanguages in languages)
        {
            this.db.MenuLanguageSet.Remove(itemLanguages);
        }

        //Accesses
        var accesses = from listAccesses in this.db.Accesses
                        where listAccesses.menuId == id
                        select listAccesses;



        foreach (var itemAccesses in accesses)
        {
            this.db.Accesses.Remove(itemAccesses);    
        }

        //DELETE CHILD
        //Menus
        var menusChild = from listmenus in this.db.Menus
                        where listmenus.parentId == id
                        select listmenus;

        foreach (var child in menusChild)
        {
            DeleteMenu(child.Id);
        }


        //delete parent
        this.db.Menus.Remove(item);
        this.db.SaveChanges();


    }
```

This is not working and I dont know why. I don't know how to make my loop.

Comment: define `this is not working`

Comment: Also, what about a cascading delete in DB should be exactly that many times more efficient as you have menu items.

Comment: cascading delete would be the better way to go and far more maintainable if you are able to

Comment: EF try to delete Child 1, but it cannot be deleted because Subchild 1 and Subchild 2 have foreign key to Child 1.

Comment: How do I made a cascading delete ?

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @austinwernli and flq: Cascade delete would have been the best solution *if SQL Server (hence EF) was supporting it for self referencing tables*. But it doesn't (error *may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths blah-blah* :)

Comment: Now constructive, besides the efficiency, the code looks ok and should be working. Please provide information (exception message etc.) what do you mean by *not working*.

Comment: EF try to delete Child 1, but it cannot be deleted because Subchild 1 and Subchild 2 have foreign key to Child 1.

Comment: But the code seem to delete the children first. Can we see the entity model and configuration if any?

Comment: Oups. The error is : New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Got it !

This is my final code :

```
    public void DeleteMenu(int id)
    {
        this.RecursiveDeleteMenu(id);
        this.db.SaveChanges();


    }
    public void RecursiveDeleteMenu(int id)
    {
        var item = this.db.Menus.Single(x => x.Id == id);

        //DELETE FOREIGN KEYS
        //MenuLanguageSet
        var languages = from listLanguages in this.db.MenuLanguageSet
                        where listLanguages.idMenu == id
                        select listLanguages;

        foreach (var itemLanguages in languages)
        {
            this.db.MenuLanguageSet.Remove(itemLanguages);
        }

        //Accesses
        var accesses = from listAccesses in this.db.Accesses
                       where listAccesses.menuId == id
                       select listAccesses;



        foreach (var itemAccesses in accesses)
        {
            this.db.Accesses.Remove(itemAccesses);
        }

        //DELETE CHILD
        //Menus
        var menusChild = from listmenus in this.db.Menus
                         where listmenus.parentId == id
                         select listmenus;

        foreach (var child in menusChild)
        {
            RecursiveDeleteMenu(child.Id);
        }


        //delete parent
        this.db.Menus.Remove(item);
    }
```

I've got the error `New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session` because `this.db.SaveChanges()` was in a loop.

Thank you everyone!